# How should invisibility be handled in Genesys?

Tags: invisibility, genesys

Every Genesys sourcebook mentions invisibility, but there's no consistent definition.

- The *Genesys Core Rulebook* says (p. 212) that an Augment spell could turn a character invisible with at least a Hard (♦︎♦︎♦︎) check, but doesn't spell out the mechanical benefits.
- The *Expanded Player's Guide* says (p. 100) that a Mask spell could turn a character invisible with a Formidable (♦︎♦︎♦︎♦︎) check.  Illusions can be detected passively with an Average (♦︎♦︎) Vigilance check or actively with an Average Perception check.
- *Realms of Terrinoth* describes (p. 102) an Invisibility Potion as granting ◼️◼️◼️◼️ of concealment.
- *Shadow of the Beanstalk* describes (p. 93) an Optical Camouflage Suit as adding one upgrade to the difficulty of spotting the wearer.

Which rule for invisibility is correct?

Comment: "Best" is a rather subjective criterion. What are your aims with the condition? Power level, accessibility, balance against other effects? Another option is to ask whether the mechanical effects *have* been described somewhere and you just missed it.

Comment: @Szega I was moderately thorough in the lit review above.  ;)  Something I missed in the rulebooks would certainly count as a substantial answer.

Comment: That was not my main point. As it is the question is opinion-based. I tried to think of ways to remedy that.

Comment: People are confused about what to do whenever invisibility arises in Genesys because there are too many correct answers.  We just had a day-long thread of people debating the issue on the Genesys Discord.  It'd be helpful to capture the result of those discussions here so we don't have to argue it out again next month.

Answer (score 2):

## Genesys has no general rule for invisibility.

Every source of invisibility is different and has its own ad hoc mechanics.  If you introduce a new source of invisibility within your setting, you are obliged to define the governing mechanics yourself.

In addition to the ones listed in the question, the following existing rules are candidates which could be adapted for new sources of invisibility:

- The **Blinded** critical injury upgrades all checks twice, and Perception and Vigilance checks three times.  Invisibility could be treated as blindness applying just to the invisible object.  Note the similarity to the Optical Camouflage Suit, which also models invisibility with difficulty upgrades.
- The Stealth skill allows the user to act unnoticed by anyone else.  Invisibility could grant automatic success at Stealth checks.
- Treating invisibility as a form of concealment (e.g. the Invisibility Potion) conveniently avoids it from stacking with other forms of concealment (e.g. darkness).

Comment: I'd suggest that automatic success at stealth checks is a bad idea for a general solution.

Comment: @Isaac What trouble do you foresee?

Comment: The simplest problem is that it doesn't take other senses into account. Nor the fact that, noise is in many stealth related situations, actually the more important factor - especially in a universe where magic exists and the guards potentially know of it.

I believe the general principle is something like: any activity that could reasonably be expected to fail (without preventing story progression), should be a check? -- Though I haven't double checked if that is principle is in Genesys, or just a habit I've picked up from other systems, and assumed is also present here.

Comment: I'm fine with it being an automatic success sometimes -- in a very noisy environment, for example. But not as a general solution.

Comment: It would honestly make invisibility too powerful. Any group that could use invisibility could stroll past anything that didn't have some way to negate it. Your setting would become a question of "who has the money for invisible-proof defenses" because anyone else is going to be robbed blind. No pun intended.

Comment: Or did you mean *an* automatic success? As in, one die result that is a success?

Comment: @ifusaso I meant "don't bother making a check to avoid being seen; there's no chance of failure because you're invisible".